# How to include model.predict into my input pipeline?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

### The problem:

I'm building a video captioning seq2seq model and I've a problem with the input pipeline:

I'm using a pre-trained **InceptionV3** model to preprocess all my data

However, I've got a lot of data: 10.000 videos containing about several hundred frames each.

When I'm using Inceptionv3 to preprocess my data, it returns me a **numpy array with a very huge size**.

It's then impossible for me to create a `tf.data.Dataset` from this numpy array because its size, 6GiB, is way bigger than **2GiB tensorflow's size limit**.

---

### My pipeline steps:

**Step 1:**

Extracting videos and storing frames on the disk. Creating a `tf.data.Dataset` from this files.

```py
record_files, lowest_n_frames = build_tfrecord_dataset(videos_name, video_path_zip, record_file_path)
records_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(record_files)
```

**Step 2:**

Taking the frames from the TFRecord files created in step 1 and reformatting it for Inceptionv3.

```py
video_dataset = records_dataset.map(lambda tfrecord: decode_tfrecord(tfrecord, n_frames))
video_dataset = video_dataset.map(format_video)
```

**Step 3:**

Preprocessing the video frames using Inceptionv3. This returns me a huge numpy array.

```py
bottlenecks = image_features_extract_model.predict(video_dataset, verbose=1, steps=n_samples)
```

**Step 4 (Error step):**

I'm creating a `tf.data.Dataset` from `bottlenecks`. Of course, it works on a small number of data.

```py
features_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(bottlenecks)
```

---

The error is very simple and straightforward:

```
ValueError: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB.
```

---

### What I would like:

I'm wondering how turning the model.predict operation as a part of my input pipeline !

I don't want to have a 6GiB numpy array in my RAM at a time, I want to do the preprocessing "step by step" over my data

Comment: How does `bottlenecks` look like?

Comment: ```bottlenecks``` is a numpy array shaped ```[n_video*n_frames, 2048]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your data gets big, its smarter to use [tf.data.Dataset.from_generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator)

I don't know what your exact code and outputs look like but it should work if you try something like this

```py
features_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(iter(bottlenecks),
                                                  output_types=...,
                                                  output_shapes=...,)
```

Comment: But, using this method I'll still have a 6GiB numpy array in my RAM !

Comment: Use [predict_generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict_generator) to convert your prediction to batches aswell

Comment: I can create a tf.data.Dataset from my bottlenecks, but I didn't achieve to use predict_generator to make my predictions "one by one".
Could you please, provide me an example using Daraset API ?

Comment: You can iterate over your `videos_dataset` and create a generator of predictions (a python generator that yields predictions from your model)